# showing Wait Screen using LWUIT in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

Is there any way of showing Wait Screen, while some processing is done in backend, using LWUIT in J2ME ? if yes then how if no then is there any alternate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [progress bar with LWUIT.](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/05/progress-indicator-threads-in-lwuit.html) Sample Wait screen used in the makeover demo and the browser demo application in [current LWUIT Repository](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show/trunk/Apps?rev=1518). Also see [here.](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/11/round-round-infinite-progress-and.html)

Comment: i have used an alternate option for this as well, showing a dialog box with wait status and no commands on it until the process finishes.

Comment: You can also use the Slider component, it has an infinite progress mode if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, but got a workaround: these suggestions here seemed not to be the best for me. The dialog when it displays will block any other action except it is discarded, even if it was created with no commands.
What I did was to add a wait screen to the BorderLayout.CENTER of the main container or the Form, then when the thread running my background task finishes, the component is now replaced with the loaded component.
I dont know if anyone would find this useful since this has already been answered. I just felt like posting my own trick.

Comment: Thanks Peter, the thing i did has the same aspects the dialog i am showing as for waitscreen is in another thread as well so when it is displayed it doesn't halts the current functionality (no matter displayed with or without commands :) ) and offcourse the solution u gave is a good one as well. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread in which you do your stuff of getting data and all and in the UI thread show the loading dialog and then dispose that loading dialog once you are done with your services call.