# LWUIT progress bar

Tags: java-me, progress-bar, lwuit, gauge

I want to show a progress bar indicating loading application at the beginning.

How can that be done? I have created a gauge but I think it cannot be implemented in LWUIT form..

Comment: Look at the existing discussion regards [progress bar.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692881/showing-wait-screen-using-lwuit-in-j2me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment, You can use progress bar. And also you can use [slider component](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/07/sliding-it-back-to-my-first-post.html) for instead of showing progress bar in LWUIT.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use canvas. You can reuse the class in all your apps and it is very efficient. Create a class, say like a class named Splash:

```
public class Splash extends Canvas {

private final int height;
private final int width;
private int current = 0;
private final int factor;
private final Timer timer = new Timer();
Image AppLogo;
MayApp MIDlet;

/**
 *
 * @param mainMIDlet
 */
public Splash(MyApp mainMIDlet) {

    this.MIDlet = mainMIDlet;
    setFullScreenMode(true);
    height = getHeight();
    width = this.getWidth();
    factor = width / 110;
    repaint();
    timer.schedule(new draw(), 1000, 01);
}

/**
 *
 * @param g
 */
protected void paint(Graphics g) {
    try {//if you want to show your app logo on the splash screen
        AppLogo = javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage("/appLogo.png");
    } catch (IOException io) {
    }
    g.drawImage(AppLogo, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.VCENTER | javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.HCENTER);
    g.setColor(255, 255, 255);
    g.setColor(128, 128, 0);//the color for the loading bar
    g.fillRect(30, (height / 2) + 100, current, 6);//the thickness of the loading bar, make it thicker by changing 6 to a higher number and vice versa
}

private class draw extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        current = current + factor;
        if (current > width - 60) {
            timer.cancel();
            try {
                //go back to your midlet or do something
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        } else {
            repaint();
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();//cleanup after yourself
    }
}
```

}

and in your MIDlet:

```
public class MyApp extends MIDlet {

Splash splashScreen = new Splash(this);

    public MyApp(){
}

public void startApp(){

    try{
        Display.init(this);
        javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(splashScreen);
        //and some more stuff
        } catch (IOException ex){}
}
//continue
```